# Python - Connecting to Snowflake - Name Error

Tags: python

I'm writing some Python code to connect to our Snowflake Database and getting an error in my Python (I'm new to Python so i've likely done something wrong here).

I'm getting <class 'NameError'> TestConnection.py 98 inside my script, which has the relevant parts below

```
def connection(obj):
    try:
        global cur, engine
        cur = obj.cursor_connection().cursor()
        engine = obj.engine_connection().engine.connect()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sql = "select current_warehouse(), current_database(), current_schema();"
    try:
        print("Cursor connection successful")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    try:
        print("Engine connection successful")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return cur, engine



try:
    #Setup Connection with both cursor and the engine
    db, schema= login.db, login.schema
    obj = connect(db, schema)
    cur , engine = connection(obj)
```

The line I'm getting the error on is the cur,engine = connection(obj) part.

I had a previous error before (UnboundLocalError) but putting global cur, engine inside the connection function fixed that, but getting NameError now.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import snowflake.connector
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
       user='<user_name>',
       password='<password>',
       account='<account_identifier>'
       )
cs = ctx.cursor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've fixed this now, it was indentation on the functions and class.

I ended up with

```
class connect:
    def __init__
    def cursor_connection
    def engine_connection
def connection
```

and that has it working whereas having def_connection tabbed in was breaking it.